# CesiumJS Create 3D Bounding Box

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, cesiumjs

I am trying to create a bounding box in CesiumJS, where the location is constantly being updated. I have looked at the tutorials from Cesium and I know how to create a box but I can't seem to create a 3D bounding box (as shown in the youtube video, link below). In the documentation I think I have to use boundingRectangle but it doesn't show up on the map. Is there something I am missing?

I am trying to achieve this image shown in this youtube video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Svmfxfu4prs&list=PLJjPiYdF7lFbhsZ_3SstXWP1Afth7sn2v&index=3#

Code:

```
var boundingBox=new Cesium.BoundingRectangle(-114.084687, 50.938343);
var geometry = Cesium.BoxGeometry.createGeometry(boundingBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
// Create an OrientedBoundingBox using a transformation matrix, a position where the box will be translated, and a scale.
var center = new Cesium.Cartesian3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
var halfAxes = Cesium.Matrix3.fromScale(new Cesium.Cartesian3(1.0, 3.0, 2.0), new Cesium.Matrix3());

var obb = new Cesium.OrientedBoundingBox(center, halfAxes);
```

[BoundingRectangle](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/BoundingRectangle.html)

Comment: How do I add the orientated bounding box to the map? I have tried `viewer.entities.add(obb)` but the box doesn't seem to show up on the map.